# Changing a table's look in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am making first steps in iPython Notebook and Pandas (and fail to find proper keywords for Google...)

Can someone tell me how to change a table's look? Here, I would like datetimes not wrapped, shorten column title to decrease a cell's width (passenger_count), and rounding floats?

[image]

Comment: You want to look at [`set_option`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) these govern the display/formatting behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my pandas setting preference, and hope it helps.

```
import pandas as pd
# max no. of rows to display
pd.options.display.max_rows = 30
# max no. of columns to display
pd.options.display.max_columns = 6

# this limit the column width
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 10
# this controls the floating rounding (precision, keep 4 decimals after .)
pd.options.display.precision = 5
```

You can put these commands on your IPython profile config file `ipython_config.py`, so that everytime you start a either Qtconsole or Notebook session, these settings will be automatically loaded.

```
c = get_config()

c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import pandas as pd',
    'pd.options.display.mpl_style = \'default\'',
    'pd.options.display.max_rows = 30',
    'pd.options.display.max_columns = 6',
    'pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False',
    'pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 28',
    'pd.options.display.precision = 5',
    'import numpy as np',
    'np.set_printoptions(precision=4, linewidth=90, threshold=25)',
    'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'
]
```

Comment: Thanks, for sharing. But I ended up renaming the columns.

Comment: Note that precision is a suggestion, it maybe preferable to use `float_format`